# Extract attribute from simple XML element in PHP

Tags: php, xml

Driving me bonkers- I've got a simple XML element, and I just want to extract the '_Code' attribute. How would I do it?

```
<?php

$responseCode = "<STATUS _Condition='FAILURE' _Code='0705' _Description='Search failed subject not found' />";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($responseCode);

print_r($xml);

$code = $xml=>@attributes=>_Code; // Parse error
$code = $xml['@attributes']['_Code']; // Returns blank
echo "CODE = ".(string)$code; 

?>
```

> CODE =

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SimpleXMLElement::attributes()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

```
$attrs = $xml->attributes();
$code = $attrs['_Code'];
```